# Datetime 12 Hour Format Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert this time format to datetime:

```
Date    Hour

05/12/17 2:15 p
05/12/17 2:20 p
05/12/17 2:25 p
```

Using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format="%I:%M %p")
```

Getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '05/12/17 2:15 p' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p' (match)
```

Comment: Datetime = date + time.  Where is the the date?

Comment: Also, the `%p` directive is the locale's equivalent of AM or PM (e.g. in the U.S., 2:15 PM would result in '1900-01-01 14:15:00' given just the time).

Comment: @Alexander Detailes added. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['05/12/17'] * 3, 
    'Hour': ['2:15 p', '2:20 p', '2:25 a']})

>>> pd.to_datetime(
        df['Date'] 
        + " " 
        + df['Hour'].str.replace('p', 'PM').str.replace('a', 'AM')
    )
0   2017-05-12 14:15:00
1   2017-05-12 14:20:00
2   2017-05-12 02:25:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that I changed the third item from 'p' to 'a' to show how it should work for AM.  I am also assuming that 'AM' and 'PM' are the correct representations in your locale.

You can add `format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'` as an argument to make the conversion more explicit.